# SQL language in MS ACCESS 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

i need help with some query in MS ACCESS 2016 with SQL language.
I have a table with 20 employers, and the table includes name, last name, gender, date of birth, date of employment and payment.
I need to calculate specific age, I mean, I want to know who is for example 25 years old of my employers, i dont know how to write command in SQL language to calculate that, i would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: Show us what you have already achieved please!

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Well, if you want to write a query the place to start is learning the language.  Tutorials, videos, books, documentation, examples, classes, online tutorials all abound to help people learn SQL and other computer languages.

Comment: I was looking for tutorials and so on but didnt find what i need, that's why i am here

Comment: How specific do you want this to be? Have you looked into using `DATEDIFF` together with your current date of birth and `DATE()` (current date)? See: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

Comment: I suggest you start with Query instead of jumping into SQL.  Look into adding the function that will calculate the age as per @jens comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate 100% correct age directly in SQL in a simple way.

So use an UDF (user defined function) like this:

```
Public Function AgeSimple( _
  ByVal datDateOfBirth As Date) _
  As Integer

' Returns the difference in full years from datDateOfBirth to current date.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap years
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'
' DateAdd() is used for check for month end of February as it correctly
' returns Feb. 28. when adding a count of years to dates of Feb. 29.
' when the resulting year is a common year.
' After an idea of Markus G. Fischer.
'
' 2007-06-26. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim datToday  As Date
  Dim intAge    As Integer
  Dim intYears  As Integer

  datToday = Date
  ' Find difference in calendar years.
  intYears = DateDiff("yyyy", datDateOfBirth, datToday)
  If intYears > 0 Then
    ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
    ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of datDateOfBirth.
    intAge = intYears - Abs(DateDiff("d", datToday, DateAdd("yyyy", intYears, datDateOfBirth)) > 0)
  End If

  AgeSimple = intAge

End Function
```

Copy and paste the code into an empty module.

Then run a query:

```
Select *, AgeSimple([DateOfBirth]) As Age
From YourTable
Where AgeSimple([DateOfBirth]) >= 25
```

Of course, replace table and field names with those of yours.